# How can I extend a trait in Rust defined somewhere else?

Tags: rust

I want to create a new iterator method such as:

```rust
let test_data = vec![1,2,3,1,1,1,1];
let indexes_with_val_1 = test_data.iter().find_all(|element| element == 1).unwrap();

assert_eq!(indexes_with_val_1, vec!(0,3,4,5,6));
```

So essentially I want to add a new method to the `std::iter::Iterator` trait but can't find examples that work for this

The logic is not an issue as I have a free function which works fine, I just would like to be able to use it as I have in the code example for better ergonomics.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a design pattern called [extension traits](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html). You can't extend the `Iterator` trait, but you can write a new one. Here's what we're going to do.

1. Write a new trait, `IteratorExt`, which has your custom method in it.
2. Write a blanket `impl` that implements `IteratorExt` for any type that implements `Iterator`.
3. Import `IteratorExt` to get access to your extension function.

For example, we can add a simple function called `my_extension` to iterators like so

```
trait IteratorExt {

  fn my_extension(self) -> Self;

}

impl<T: Iterator> IteratorExt for T {

  fn my_extension(self) -> Self {
    println!("Hey, it worked!");
    self
  }

}

pub fn main() {
  let x = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);
  let y = x.iter().my_extension().map(|x| x + 1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
  println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

The only downside is that you have to import the new trait to use it. So if you want to use `my_extension` in another file, you have to import `IteratorExt` specifically in order to do so.

In my experience, the Rust community is somewhat divided on whether this is legitimate practice or whether it's a hack to be avoided, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Explained really well, I didn't get this at all until I read your answer. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

There exist [the extension trait pattern](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html) for that.

The idea is that you create a trait, usually named `TraitExt` by convention, and implement it for all implementations of `Trait`:

```rust
pub trait IteratorExt {
    fn my_iterator_extension(&self);
}

impl<I: Iterator + ?Sized> IteratorExt for I {
    fn my_iterator_extension(&self) {
        // Do work.
    }
}

my_iterator.my_iterator_extension();
```